# LoaderCallbacks implementation for record deletion

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-loadermanager

There is a custom ContentProvider for data access to an SQLite on the device. In the View i implement the LoaderCallbacks. Each View uses a single database row by binding to a URI with appended record id (URI/ID) in the onCreateLoader Method of the View (implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks).

So let's assume there are 3 Views on the screen, each one "representing" one line in the database. Now a background sync process deletes a row by calling the delete method of the ContentProvider (URI/ID). The row is removed from the database in the delete method of the ContentProvider and the onLoadFinished Callbacks of the corresponding View with the right ID is triggered, getting a cursor with getCount() = 0, because the row is no longer existing.

**First Question:**
Is this already wrong and there should be a onLoaderReset callback at this moment?

**If yes to Q1:**

The ContentProvider delete method does a delete on one ID in the SQLite:

```
deletedRows = db.delete("table", "_id="+uri_id, selectionArgs);
```

then calls notifyChange and returns the deleted row count:

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
return deletedRows;
```

So how to implement this to get onLoaderReset callback called in this process? (at the moment it is not called)

**If no to Q1, Second Question:**
If the row is no longer existing i want to remove the View from the UI. Is there anything wrong to do something like:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {  
  if( cursor.getCount() > 0){
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    //Populate elements with cursors data
  }else{
    //remove this view completely
  } 
}
```

I am not sure that this is good practice because in this example the trigger for "row was removed" is an empty cursor, is this the best way?

I can not use a technical listview by the way, i need single Views (FrameLayouts) bound to their data with URI/ID.

Thanks a lot for your effort!

Comment: so use ListView with an. adapter that returns Views (FrameLayouts) in getView() method

Comment: The FrameLayouts should be flexible enough to use them not only in ListViews, so they should be able to detect when the are "no longer needed" by themselves, not only being removed by a parent ListView because of a re-render.

Comment: and is it the reason you cannot use a ListView?